# How to change a url subdirectory to a variable in retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin

Any Idea how can I change the id subdirectory to a variable that will takes the value of the function argument?
The id query is incorrect since it's gonna be after information.

```
@GET("recipes/id/information")
suspend fun getRecipeInformation(
    @Query("id")
     id: Int,
    @Query("apiKey")
     apiKey: String) : Response<RecipesByIngredientsResponse>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you have to define the *id* argument as a *Path* variable, instead of *Query*:

```
@GET("recipes/{id}/information")
suspend fun getRecipeInformation(
    @Path("id")
     id: Int,
    @Query("apiKey")
     apiKey: String) : Response<RecipesByIngredientsResponse>
```

Notice the syntax:

- the *id* is in curly braces
- *Path* annotation is used instead of *Query*

Official documentation: [Path](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html)